# mutate new column based on indexing (by words)

Tags: string, dplyr

I am currently tidying my data but am stuck at the following point..
I want to calculate the mean (new column) out of several columns which contain certain words.
In addition, I want the mean to be calculated rowwise.

Currently, I tried the following code which does not work.
Thanks a lot for your help!!

```
df %>%
      mutate(
        mean_c =  rowMeans(subset(df, select = str_ends(string = "mp_ver_final_org", pattern = "org"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df <- iris
df %>% 
  select(ends_with("Length")) %>% # Select columns with a given pattern
  mutate(mean = rowMeans(.))      # Compute mean row-wise

    Sepal.Length Petal.Length mean
1            5.1          1.4 3.25
2            4.9          1.4 3.15
3            4.7          1.3 3.00
4            4.6          1.5 3.05
```